# Django rest Framework Endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls, endpoint

I need to get this endpoint /comments/int:post_id/
I can GET and POST comments and posts but I need to show all comments to specific post. I don´t know how to connect it. My code look like

comment urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CommentsView.as_view()),
    path('<int:post_id>/', views.CreateCommentsView.as_view()),
]
```

comment view.py

```
# I get all comments/
class CommentsView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

# Comments to specific post
class CreateCommentsView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'post_id'

     def perform_create(self,serializer):
         post = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
         post =set.get_queryset().filter(id = 'post_id')
         post.comments.add(comment)
         post = Post.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
         serializer.save(user=self.request.user, post=post)
```

comment serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Comment
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'post', 'content', 'created']

class UserSimpleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']

class CommentSimpleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSimpleSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['user', 'content', 'created']
```

post.view.py

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

class LikePost(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsNotPostUser]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Comment: Take look into https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the `post_id` in url parameters for `/comments/` endpoint and call HTTP GET method. Then in `CommentsView` you need to override the `get_queryset` method. Your implementation will be like

```
class CommentsView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.query_params.get('post_id', None)
        if query is not None:
            queryset = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=post_id)
        else:
            queryset = Comment.objects.all()
       return queryset
```

This `/comments/` endpoint will return all the comments and this one `/comments/?post_id=1` will return comments only related to specified post.